# Upload file to iCloud, sometimes file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, upload, icloud

I want to upload some files to iCloud and use this:

```
FileDocument *doc = [[FileDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:des];
    doc.data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:src];
    NSLog(@"Local url: %@", src);
    NSLog(@"Remote url: %@", des);
    [doc saveToURL:des forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Success");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Fail ");
        }
    }];
```

After the success log, I open iCloud > Storage > Manage Storage on my iPad to check if file exist. Sometimes the file appear and sometimes not.